# Execution time of sequential asynchronous process and division of labour

Tags: scheduling

I wasn't sure if I should put this question here, but I guess is as good as any.

When we have a sequential process that has a number of tasks, were each task requires the previous one to be completed, and we have as many machines as tasks, and all machines execute each task in the same time (no difference in task time across machines, but each task time might be different), and can function simultaneously, but requiring subproducts from the previous machine in the process.

The working time to generate a result/product will be more or less the maximum task time in the process among machines, at least after a cycle.

But, If one machine could be assigned to each next task after finishing the previous one, that is, if each machine is assigned the whole process instead of a single task, the total time per process or product will be the sum of times for the tasks divided by the number of machines.

Because in the second case there is no idle time, the second case is always the optimal time to complete processes, and the first one can only be as good if all the tasks have the same required time.

Assuming no cost of switching, starting task, etc. Is this correct?

**Background**

I started reading The Wealth of Nations by Adam Smith were it encourages the division of labor, based on 3 things:

- Less requirements in skill and faster learning in workers for simpler tasks.
- Time saved by avoiding switching tasks.
- Simpler tasks increase focus on themselves and facilitate the creation of technology.

But, if we ignore these points, when the workers are very skilled, and there are no switching costs, it is better optimized to assign each worker to the whole process instead of individual subtasks. As I just shown in my previous question.

I just wanted to make this clear that actually, formally, division of labor is only beneficial because of certain constraints but its not the optimal strategy, although it might be the most efficient in a sense. Seems counterintuitive.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. If I can understand your question correctly, your issue is divided into two parts. The first, assigning tasks into the machines in an optimal manner (or sequencing), and the second, allocating the operators in each machine, (or Man-Machine allocation). For the first, do you have any specific tools, like either mathematical models or any heuristics? For the second, have you seen something like the Man-machine chart to optimize the required operators?